# How to transfer music (purchased from Google Play Music) from Android to Windows?

Tags: file-transfer, music

How do I transfer music from my Android phone to MS Windows? It only shows me the songs from the music app and not the Play Music app with the songs I've purchased.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access all of your Google Play music on a computer: [Google Play Music](http://music.google.com/music/listen#start_pl). You can download any purchased music though the browser. For instance: I purchased an album from Google Play and it is available for download using the website on the computer (see image).

Hope this helps[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Bxa.png)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was go to Google Play and downloaded my music. After that the little download bar shows up (bad at explaining things). Than I just hit Save As to my music and... Shazam! my music is saved to my laptop. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

most probably the songs that you have downloaded using google play music app are drm protected, that could be the reason you are not able transfer them to your laptop.